# sed remove all capital letters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to delete all occurences of Capital Letters only in the following string with the sed command below but it is only outputting the sting that I enter - how do I put the substitution in correctly ?

```
echo "Dog boy Did Good" | sed 's/\([A-Z]\+\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
echo "Dog boy Did Good" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Dog boy Did Good" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'
og boy id ood
```

You substitute something (UPPERCASE) with nothing, and you don't need to group it, because you don't use it later, and you don't need +, because the g in the end performs the substitution globally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove them completely, don't use \1 in the second half of the sed expression, since that adds in the first match (which is what you're trying to replace)

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have now are good, assuming all your upper case letters are represented via `[A-Z]`, as is standard in regular American English, but [fails the Turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html), which has several variants of the letter `i`.

Better would be to use the `[[:upper:]]` mechanism, which will respect the current `locale(7)`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:upper:]]//g' /etc/motd
elcome to buntu 11.04 (/inux 2.6.38-12-generic x86_64)
...
```

Another alternative that I want to mention; the `tr(1)` command can do deletions easily:

```
$ tr -d [[:upper:]] < /etc/motd 
elcome to buntu 11.04 (/inux 2.6.38-12-generic x86_64)
...
```

Comment: In German, I receive for `echo "Über Öko-Äpfel TNT" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'` the result `ber ko-pfel`. Übüntü 10.04.3, LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8

Comment: But I remember the times, when it doesn't - a couple of years ago. :)